# wordpress htaccess redirected www to folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have the subdomain `sub.main.com` which is redirected to `www.sub.main.com/sub` for some reason, causing a 404.

FWIW, this is what my `.htaccess` file looks like in the root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

default wordpress `.htaccess` in sub

---

#### Edit

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39299314/2748327) proposed by @anubhava has fixed the first problem, being that `sub.main.com` was redirected to `www.sub.main.com/sub`, removing the `www`; however, this still redirects to `sub.main.com/sub`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^main\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: How should `sub.main.com` be redirected?

Comment: sub.main.com you stick to showing sub.main.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep redirect rule at top and make it target only main domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^main\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

---

#### Edit:

Removing the `www` in the `RewriteRule` has solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've tried adding this to the `sub.main.com` htaccess` file and the `main.com .htaccess` files (together, and seperately); all this has done is remove the `www`, but I still have `sub.main.com/sub`, even when I try to access `sub.main.com/wp-admin`.

Comment: Are you getting `sub.main.com/sub` instead of `www.sub.main.com/sub` now? Are `DocumentRoot` for `main.com` and `sub.main.com` different?

Comment: No, my `DocumentRoot`s are different; I have `/public_html/` as root for `main.com` and `/public_html/sub` for `sub.main.com`; and yes, I am getting `sub.main.com/sub` now, but I still need to have `sub.main.com` as I am getting a 404 on `sub`'s home page. Both directories are WordPress installs.

Comment: ok if you comment out this `www` enforcing rule and retest after clearing browser cache does it change behavior?

Comment: BOOM ! I Thank you, @anubhava, you've saved me on a nice Friday afternoon! Enjoy your weekend !